# 'Filename' error when trying to do Image Augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am trying to implement image augmentation of the fruits data set and now without doing this augmentation part my model runs but validation accuracy is low (very low)
so i tried for this method and i ran into this problem

```
train_data,val_data = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data,test_size=0.2)
print(train_data.shape)
print(val_data.shape)
```

> > (45191, 2)
> > (11298, 2)

```
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',    
)
​
validation_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
​
train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = train_data,
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    target_size=(300, 300),
    shuffle = True,
    subset = 'training'
)
​
val_data = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = val_data,
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    target_size=(300, 300),
    shuffle = False,
    subset = 'validation'
)
```

[image]

Getting this error *"Filename"* at the end

Comment: You should look at the keras documentation on how exactly flow_from_dataframe works, it is meant to get data from a dataframe, and you have to tell keras which columns of the dataframe to use, so Filename is just a default value of the column for the X variables.

Comment: Yes i updated the things as per the documentation requested Thanks so much @Dr.Snoopy